# Cannot display webview window using PHP FFI

Tags: php, build, gtk, webkit, ffi

I am trying to use the [webview](https://github.com/webview/webview) library using PHP FFI. On my Manjaro linux, using the prebuilt binary from the manjaro package repo, everthing works great. Here's the code that's working with the prebuilt binary,

```php
// Define the library path and the corresponding C declarations
$cdef = "
typedef void *webview_t;
webview_t webview_create(int debug, void *window);
void webview_navigate(webview_t w, const char *url);
void webview_run(webview_t w);
";
$libpath = '/path/to/libwebview.so';

// Load the shared library
$ffi = FFI::cdef($cdef, $libpath);

// Call the webview_create function
$handle = $ffi->webview_create(1, null);

// Call the webview_navigate function
$ffi->webview_navigate($handle, "https://stackoverflow.com/");

// Call the webview_run function
$ffi->webview_run($handle);
```

This produces the following window,
[image: Window opened from prebuilt php binary]

But if I try the same thing with a binary built on my own machine, all I get is a blank window and a "warning" on my console.
[image]

```
(WebKitWebProcess:17649): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:08:37.793: cannot open display:
```

For building php, this is the configure command that I've used,

```
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/target --with-config-file-scan-dir=$(pwd)/target/lib/conf.d --enable-zts --with-curl --with-ffi
make -j16
make install
```

Edit: It works great from python. [Here](https://gist.github.com/nazmulpcc/b52529610956940aace1a35263184281) is what I've tried in python.

Comment: It looks like a *nix configuration problem. Did you install the GTK and WebKit2GTK libraries as documented in the manual?

Comment: I did. If it was a problem with *nix configuration, it would not work with the prebuilt PHP, right? or that is still possible?

Comment: Why do you build your own PHP then? If you need curl, ffi and so on, you could just install those modules.

Comment: The prebuilt PHP is "NTS" where the PHP extension "parallel" cannot be used. I am building my own to see if I can use that to controll multiple webview windows. Also, I want this to be "portable". So only working on my machine is not good enough.

Comment: We need some more details about your configuration to reproduce. What about https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi ?

Comment: I have seen that question before, so I have tried `xhost +` and similar, checking my `DISPLAY` variable, which is set to `:1` and is accessible from PHP. I am not doing ssh, so I ruled out those as unrelated.